# Как открыть интерфейс Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

Установил Anacondu на Linux, брал [здесь](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/).

Все установилось без ошибок, но в меню новых программ не добавилось. Как открыть интерфейс Anaconda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не пользовался, но, насколько я понимаю, графического интерфейса там вообще нет. Однако, есть GUI-ный Anaconda Navigator.

https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/navigator/

Comment: спасибо, в прицнипе то, запустил Anaconda Navigator и с нее установил   jupyter.